# Insert Timestamp in Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

i am trying to create a hive table where i am putting data from my hdfs, but while inserting the data i want to add the data insertion time in my table. I don't know how to do it, if you guys can help it would be wonderful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` this would insert the timestamp in your table.

`select column1 ,columns2 , from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as timestamp from table`, would work for you.